# QuickBlox Declaring file uploaded

Tags: request, quickblox

I use QuickBlox api. I make a request for Declaring file uploaded.

Picture is displayed on the server, but in response Unexpected ''

[my request in postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvHw7.png)

Comment: what HTTP status do you receive? What's in Raw tab in response?

Comment: http status is 200, raw is empty

Comment: then everything is OK, response body should be empty,
just check 200 OK status